# Number of 5-regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I have to find a number of 5-regular non isomorphic graphs with 8 vertices.
I just want to check if the answer is 2? My logic is to draw cycles $C_5+C_3$ and $C_4+C_4$, and since the degree of every vertex in cycle is $2$ then in the complement degree will be $8-1-2=5$. Is this correct?

Comment: There's also $C_8$...

Comment: Yes, right. And what about $6$ regular graphs with $8$ vertices? I think that is complement of graph with $4$ paths of length $1$(because every vertex in that graph is degree 1, so in complement it will be degree $6$). Is there more?

Comment: You are correct on that one; there is up to isomorphism only one $6$-regular graph on $8$ vertices.